# Plugging Pact into CI / CD

Tags: testing, pact

I would like to as some basic questions concerning plugging Pact into CI / CD workflow:
 - I understand that pact publication / verification should be done in the CI step, then during CD we check whether it is possible to deploy a service using existing data from compatibility matrix (can-i-deploy) ?
 - In my project, the CD environments for non-PROD and PROD are completely separated, so do I need to have two separate Pact Broker instances and somehow synchronize them ? We could check compatibility only during non-PROD deployment, but PROD can contain different versions of applications which are possibly not compatible with the one deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to share a single Pact Broker instance between the two environments, that would be the ideal solution. You should tag each application version with the relevant stage when you deploy to it (eg.`test`, `prod`) and use these tags when you perform the can-i-deploy check, passing in the relevant stage. The can-i-deploy logic relies on the history that you build up in a single broker. You could potentially sync between two brokers, but it would be quite fiddly. I'd only explore this option once you have ruled out the possibility of using one.

I recommend reading the [Effective Pact setup guide](https://docs.pact.io/best_practices/pact_nirvana) if you haven't already. Ping me on the pact-broker channel if you get stuck.